# Makefile compiling C files on Windows8 and files with no file extension/s

Tags: file, makefile, file-extension

I have gcc in my Win8 path and can compile C files from the Windows command prompt which is great and I have been compiling regularly in this way but just now I have been looking at creating a makefile to use and compile with.

My first makefile failed as I created makefile.txt but when I removed the file .txt extension the compile worked successfully with the make command at the cursor in cmd console.

The makefile then has no file extension and my query is how the xxxx does this work? Windows obviously knows what this file is and uses it with gcc to compile but how/why? This leads on to another question ...are there other files made with no file extension that do stuff on Windows (or other OS)? I'm perplexed and intrigued and would appreciate a technical explanation if possible.
Thanks.

EDIT...Sat 291114
I am working through Learning C the hard way by Zed Shaw and this image shows Ex2 creating a makefile on my Win8 PC..

[image: Creating a makefile on my Win8PC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works because the `make` program is written to look for files named `makefile`, not files named `makefile.txt`.

Extensions are important on Windows so that Windows can guess what "type" of file it is, so if you tried to open that file Windows could guess at what program should be used to open it.

However, this is really a problematic solution.  First, just because two files have an extension of "foo" doesn't mean both are the same type of file; there's no central authority of file extensions (that I'm aware of) to guarantee there are no conflicts.  Second, just because a file has an extension "foo" doesn't mean the *contents* are of that type: I'm sure you're familiar with viruses and scams where a file of one type is created with a different extension to trick Windows into running an unexpected program.

On traditional UNIX-based systems the "type" of a file is usually derived from the *contents* of the file, not the extension.  There are some obvious exceptions, for example source files are all plain text files so they have the type of code it is (C, C++, Java, Python, etc.) marked by the extension.  But on UNIX systems, for example, programs do not have `.exe` extensions: for example it's just `make`, not `make.exe`.  Also a shell script doesn't have to end in `.bat` or `.com`: it can be just named `foo` as well if you want.  For executable files the operating system looks at the first two bytes of the file to tell what kind of executable it is.  For scripts the first two bytes must be `#!`: then the operating system knows it needs to run an interpreter (like the shell, or Python, or whatever) for the script.

For non-executable files like JPG or whatever, programs can determine their type by examining the contents.  Most file types have some format to their content that can be used to say "this is a JPG file", "this is a MP3 music file", etc.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply and explanation :-)